# How can I assign multiple divs with different colors to multiple buttons in a menu to indicate "active"?

Tags: javascript, background-color, onchange

I am a JavaScript beginner and I am trying to solve the following problem: I have a menu where each button addresses the div below it. Each div has a different color as a sign for "active".
When link 1 is clicked, I want the associated div to be blue, all others remain white. When link 2 is clicked, the associated div turns red, all others stay white, etc.

At the moment all buttons react to the "click", but then stay colored when I click the next div.
Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this?

Here is the code as far as I got:

HTML:

```
<body class="container">
        <div class="body">
            <aside class="sidebar">
            
                <nav id="menu-desc">                  
                    <button  class="button" id="button1">Link 1</button>
                    <div class="menu-item-box"  id="box1"></div>                 
                   <button class="button" id="button2">Link 2</button>
                    <div class="menu-item-box"  id="box2"></div>                
                    <button class="button" id="button3">Link 3</button>
                    <div class="menu-item-box"  id="box3"></div>                
                    <button class="button" id="button4">Link 4</button>
                    <div class="menu-item-box"  id="box4"></div>                                   
                    <button class="button" id="button5">Link 5</button>
                    <div class="menu-item-box"  id="box5"></div>                              
                </nav>     
            </aside>   

    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 10px;
    top: 0;
  }

.body {
  display: flex;
 }
  
/* == Menu == */
  
.sidebar {
   width: 500px;    
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  height: 2em;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-left: calc(5px + 3vw);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-style: none;
 }
  
.menu-item-box {
  height: 3em;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

JS:

```
let button1 = document.querySelector("#button1");
        button1.addEventListener('click',function(){
        document.querySelector("#box1").style.backgroundColor="Blue";
        });

let button2 = document.querySelector("#button2");
        button2.addEventListener('click',function(){
        document.querySelector("#box2").style.backgroundColor="red";
        });

let button3 = document.querySelector("#button3");
        button3.addEventListener('click',function(){
        document.querySelector("#box3").style.backgroundColor="green";
        });

let button4 = document.querySelector("#button4");
        button4.addEventListener('click',function(){
        document.querySelector("#box4").style.backgroundColor="yellow";
        });

let button5 = document.querySelector("#button5");
        button5.addEventListener('click',function(){
        document.querySelector("#box5").style.backgroundColor="purple";
        });
```

On W3Schools there is an example of how to activate in single classes, but it only goes through with a single background color there. I don't know how I could modify that so it doesn't address the button itself and the colors change per div. ([https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_active_element](https://stackoverflow.com)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */
.active, .btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Active Button</h1>
<p>Highlight the active/current (pressed) button.</p>
  
<div id="myDIV">
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn active">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
  <button class="btn">4</button>
  <button class="btn">5</button>
</div>

<script>
// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
  this.className += " active";
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is not meant to be copy/pasted. Imagine you had 100 BUTTONSs and 100 DIVs. The task of managing such code would become a nightmare.
Instead:

- use [data-* attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to store the ID selector to target
- use inline (only for that specific case!) in order to store a CSS var like `--bg` for your DIVs
- use that CSS variable `var(--bg)` in your styles to apply the background value once the elements gets a `.is-active`
- in JavaScript cache your elements into variables
- in JavaSCript, on click get the target id from the data-* attribute using `Element.dataset`
- use Element.classList.toggle("className", boolean) in JavaSCript in your click event

```js
// Cache your elements
const elsButtons = document.querySelectorAll("#menu-desc .button");
const elsBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("#menu-desc .menu-item-box");

elsButtons.forEach(elBtn => {
  elBtn.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
    elsBoxes.forEach(elBox => {
      elBox.classList.toggle("is-active", elBox.id === elBtn.dataset.targetid);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; }
/* don't use margin:10px and specially not top:0; when using "*" selector. */

.button {
  display: block;
  height: 2rem;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-left: calc(5px + 3vw);
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-item-box {
  height: 3em;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-left: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.menu-item-box.is-active {
  background-color: var(--bg);
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu-desc">
  <button class="button" data-targetid="box1">Link 1</button>
  <div class="menu-item-box" style="--bg:#00f;" id="box1"></div>
  <button class="button" data-targetid="box2">Link 2</button>
  <div class="menu-item-box" style="--bg:#f00;" id="box2"></div>
  <button class="button" data-targetid="box3">Link 3</button>
  <div class="menu-item-box" style="--bg:#0f0;" id="box3"></div>
  <button class="button" data-targetid="box4">Link 4</button>
  <div class="menu-item-box" style="--bg:#ff0;" id="box4"></div>
  <button class="button" data-targetid="box5">Link 5</button>
  <div class="menu-item-box" style="--bg:#f0f;" d="box5"></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hello Roko,

thank you very much for your quick help. From my code you have quickly recognized that I am still a complete beginner : ). I have so much cross-read and tried and then got totally confused.
I had this problem especially with a website design, but I will now gradually create the Javascript basics on it and make small exercises for me so that I do not despair so quickly.
Thank you!